# Sum number according to date and name in excel

Tags: excel

To sum the third column (numbers o companies) I've used this
`=SUM(1/COUNTIF(Names;Names))`

Names is name of array in C column  and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and it works perfectly.

Now I'd like to sum earnings but only for each company once and with the latest data. For example, the result shoud be like this

`=C4+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10`
 (93)

Thanks

```
        A     B         C         D 
1    #  company    earnings  date
2    1    ISB       12    10/11/2011
3    2    DTN       15    11/11/2011
4    3    ABC       13    12/11/2011
5    4    ISB       17    13/11/2011
6    5    RTV       18    14/11/2011
7    6    DTN       22    15/11/2011
8    7    PVS       11    16/11/2011
9    8    ISB       19    17/11/2011
10   9    ANH       10    18/11/2011
Sum        6        93
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ascending dates, you could try with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in C11:

```
=SUM((MAX(A2:A10)-MATCH(B2:B10,LOOKUP(MAX(A2:A10)-A2:A10,A2:A10-1,B2:B10),0)=A2:A10-1)*C2:C10)
```

Comment: +1 top formula lori_m - I need to sit down for a moment and try to understand how it works!

Comment: @barryhoudini - Thanks, I spent about an hour figuring it out! LOOKUP is basically just reversing the array for use in MATCH. Based on your suggestion, I think  a slightly simpler variant would be: `=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B10,MAX(A2:A10)-1,,A2:A10-MAX(A2:A10)-1),B2:B10)=1)*C2:C10)` but it is volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a helper column as the easiest approach. In E2 use this formula

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$1000,B2)=1,C2,"")`

and copy down the column. Now sum column D for the required answer.

Note that the above formula assumes 1000 rows of data maximum, increase if required.

Comment: it's easy and actually works :) but I cannot add a special column but thanks